# Ideas how to search & replace post_content when string contains a newline?

Tags: query, search, mysql, regex

I've previously been able to search & replace using the very helpful "Search & Replace" plugin for wordpress but now i've came across a problem i cannot solve.

In table wp_posts i want to replace the following:

```
</div>

<div id="postbottom">
```

with:

```
</div><div id="postbottom">
```

No matter how i input the search string i get 0 results, how do i search & replace when the string contains a newline? I've tried strings such as

```
</div>\n<div id="postbottom">
```

but this has yeilded no results.

The possibility would perhaps to execute a query directly in the sql database? How would i go about forming such a complex query to search based on a string that contains a newline? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

that was easy to do directly in sql:

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET post_content = replace(post_content,'</div>\r\n\r\n<div id="postbottom">','</div><div id="postbottom">');
```